# Deja Dup: Change Day of Weekly Backup

Tags: 18.04, deja-dup

Is it possible to change the day that weekly backups occur with Deja Dup (Ubuntu "Backups")? It is currently set to backup every Thursday, which doesn't always work with my schedule.

Comment: It seems that you can't. It doesn't use cron and doesn't have any settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Deja Dup doesn't use cron and doesn't have any settings.

See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/479191)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,, you can!  There's a workaround.

Post #40 in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/479191) by Naël (nathanael-naeri)  suggested making a manual backup with it on the day of the week and time of day you wish to use henceforth.

Comment: That had no effect on my system. I started a manual backup on Saturday night, but even after that, dejadup still started its backup on Thursday.